# resort nested array content with spread operator

Tags: javascript

I`m trying to reconstruct an nested Java Script Object but i cant make the nested spread operator work !
this is my object :

```js
let a = [{
    id: '1111',
    type: {
      id: 'aaa',
    },
  },
  {
    id: '2222',
    type: {
      id: 'aaa',
    },
  },
  {
    id: '3333',
    type: {
      id: 'bbb',
    },
  },
]

a = a.reduce((acc, val) => {
  return { ...acc, [val.type.id]: [{ [val.id]: val }] }
}, {})

console.log(a)
```

i know i should add another spread operator to my code !
note that id of "type" of first and second are similar !
expected output :

```
result = {
  aaa: [
    {
      id: "1111",
      type: {
        id: "aaa",
      },
    },
    {
      id: "2222",
      type: {
        id: "aaa",
      },
    },
  ],
  bbb: [
    {
      id: "3333",
      type: {
        id: "bbb",
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the part you are missing `[...(acc[val.type.id] || []), val]`

```js
let a = [{
    id: '1111',
    type: {
      id: 'aaa',
    },
  },
  {
    id: '2222',
    type: {
      id: 'aaa',
    },
  },
  {
    id: '3333',
    type: {
      id: 'bbb',
    },
  },
]

const b = a.reduce((acc, val) => ({
  ...acc,
  [val.type.id]: [...(acc[val.type.id] || []), val] })
, {})
console.log(b)
```

Or using nullish coalescing `[...(acc[val.type.id] ?? []), val]`

```js
let a = [{
    id: '1111',
    type: {
      id: 'aaa',
    },
  },
  {
    id: '2222',
    type: {
      id: 'aaa',
    },
  },
  {
    id: '3333',
    type: {
      id: 'bbb',
    },
  },
]

const b = a.reduce((acc, val) => ({
  ...acc,
  [val.type.id]: [...(acc[val.type.id] ?? []), val] })
, {})
console.log(b)
```